# Draw UIImage on a custom color canvas

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to draw a image for example on black canvas, but the the result is always white, here is my code

```
-(UIImage*) renderImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(300, 300));
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    UIImage*resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```

for the future i will draw an image inside the canvas, but right now i just want a black filled canvas. why this code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor()` to fill the current context with a color. Try this sample code, you give it a color and a size and it will return you a UIImage meeting your criteria.

```
- (UIImage *)renderImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color inSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```